How to determine Easter Holiday Date in Salesforce?
We have need to track the list of Holidays in Salesforce and I have entered all the holidays in the standard object which SF provides - Holidays
For example - Indenpendence Day, its on 4 July every year and we can set it up as recurring for this date.
Thanks Giving Day - its on last thursday of November and we can set this also as recurring by last thursday.
But for Easter holiday, its first Sunday after the full Moon that occurs on or after the spring equinox.
How do we determine the date for Easter holiday based on the above rule. Has anyone figured out way to this?  Please let me know appreciate your inputs.

https://www.oremus.org/liturgy/etc/ktf/app/easter.html

You will need to do some research and write an algorithm from that.
